# Segment Control Font size not changing in swift

Tags: swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a segmented control and I'm trying to change the font size of the segment titles. I have tried multiple code but it isn't working. This is how I'm changing font size of segmented control:

```
let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
segmentControl.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font: font], for: .normal)
```

But when I run the app it isn't changing the font size.
This is my all code in viewDidLoad:

```
let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
segmentControl.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font: font], for: .normal)
let titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red]
segmentControl.setTitleTextAttributes(titleTextAttributes, for: .selected)
segmentControl.fallBackToPreIOS13Layout(using: UIColor.clear)
segmentControl.font(name: "Helvetica", size: 16)
let titleTextAttributesForSelected = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
let titleTextAttributesForNormal = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.gray]
segmentControl.setTitleTextAttributes(titleTextAttributesForSelected, for: .selected)
segmentControl.setTitleTextAttributes(titleTextAttributesForNormal, for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this:

```
    let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)

    let normalAttribute: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [.font: font, .foregroundColor: UIColor.gray]
    segmentControl.setTitleTextAttributes(normalAttribute, for: .normal)

    let selectedAttribute: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [.font: font, .foregroundColor: UIColor.red]
    segmentControl.setTitleTextAttributes(selectedAttribute, for: .selected)
```

Comment: Please update your answer with an explanation of what was wrong and how this answer fixes the issue. Code-only answers are frowned upon.

Comment: Working fine now. @W.M

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
let font: [AnyHashable : Any] = [NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10)]

segmentControl.setTitleTextAttributes(font as! [NSAttributedString.Key : Any], for: .normal)
```